# update-grub2 creates grub.cfg.new instead of grub.cfg

Tags: debian, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

When I run `update-grub2` on my Debian Buster server, instead of creating a `grub.cfg` it creates a `grub.cfg.new`, even though `grub.cfg` does not exist.

And because of this my machine boots into a broken grub, because it cannot find `grub.cfg`.

Is there a way to tell `update-grub2` to create `grub.cfg` instead of `grub.cfg.new`.

Comment: The .new is created whenever you have a typo in any of the grub files used to create grub.cfg. I once forgot a closing } in 40_custom. It then showed error as last line which did not help much, but it may show error line. Also could be in /etc/default/grub, if line not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` using Ansible, it created the same .new extention.

But when I used `grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it ran successfully and created `grub.cfg`.

`-o` might not be the same as `>`.

Looking at the source code after @oldfred 's comment, found out that the `.new` extension is created when there is an error in either `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/grub.d/*` files. See [here](https://github.com/rhboot/grub2/blob/master/util/grub-mkconfig.in):

```
if test "x${grub_cfg}" != "x" ; then
  if ! ${grub_script_check} ${grub_cfg}.new; then
    # TRANSLATORS: %s is replaced by filename
    gettext_printf "Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
%s file attached." "${grub_cfg}.new" >&2
    echo >&2
    exit 1
  else
    # none of the children aborted with error, install the new grub.cfg
    mv -f ${grub_cfg}.new ${grub_cfg}
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` instead.

Comment: I gave this a try earlier, instead of me running this command Ansible ran it and it created the same .new extension, but when I ran it normally, it created `grub.cfg`. At least according to the question, this answer is right, I am gonna accept it.